# Llamar ruta en ajax codeigniter

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

Estoy tratando de integrar un modulo hecho en **PHP** (sin framework) en un sistema que esta realizado con codeigniter...

Quiero realizar una petición `AJAX` a unos de lo archivos, pero la ruta no la reconoce ya que efectivamente no esta declarada en el archivo `route.php`. Hay alguna manera de que reconozca la ruta a la cual quiero hacer la petición de manera especifica, ya que estos archivos que quiero asociar se encuentran en otra ubicación del servidor

```
 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        url: '/home/public_html/application/views/backend/notas/controller/ajax_datos.php', 
        data: {'case':'ConsultarGrupos', 'id':id},
        success: function(response, xhr, settings){
           ...
        },error: function(){ 
           ...
        }
  });
```

Quiero que reconozca la ruta de la forma que puse aquí, es esto posible ?

Comment: Codeigniter es un framework de PHP.

Comment: El archivo al que quieres hacer la petición Ajax es independiente, o hace uso de mas archivos del modulo para poder responder??

Comment: Es un archivo  independiente, solo quiero hacer el llamado de la ruta de la forma que planeado en código que puse la pregunta ya que en esa ruta se encuentra el archivo que necesito, pero codeigniter no reconoce la ruta ya que se archivo no hace parte de ese proyecto, ni esa ruta la tengo declarada, entonces quiero saber cómo sería posible poder hacer la petición a esa ruta

Comment: Utiliza el comando base_url()/controlador/metodo y podras acceder.

Comment: es un archivo que no hace parte del proyecto, no deja acceder...

Answer (score -1):

en caso de que el otro modulo este hecho usando el patron mvc , tendrías que exponer los datos del archivo ajax_datos.php en una ruta publica para que accedieras mediante una url como esta : http://localhost/miruta, en caso de que el otro modulo no use el patron mvc, podrías acceder con http://localhost/application/views/backend/notas/controller/ajax_datos.php, siempre y cuando todo este en el mismo servidor.